# how to send a string to a method in com interface?

Tags: c#, c++, com-interop

```
    cVector3d newPosition = tool->getDeviceGlobalPos();
    char sendBuf[sizeof(double)*3 + 1];
    int sendBufLen = sizeof(double)*3 + 1;

     memset( (void *)&sendBuf, '\0', sizeof(sendBuf));
    memcpy(&sendBuf, &newPosition[0], sendBufLen -1);
```

where cpi is a pointer to a com interface's object.
Multicast is a c# method which accepts string arguments.
When I print the message.length that Multicast has received, which is sendBuf it just says 2 instead of 24.

reference for cvector3d http://www.chai3d.org/doc/structc_vector3d.html

what is wrong with `cpi->Multicast(sendBuf);` ?

--edit-- I need to convert sendBuf to _bstr_t I think

I converted to _bstr_t but the message.length still shows 2 instead of 24?

I used

```
_bstr_t bstrt(sendBuf);
```

I guess bstr is corrupt as when I debug I see a `BAD PTR` in `bstr->m_data->m_str`

---

----edit----
Whnen I convert 
"123456789012378901234"

```
char sendBuf[sizeof(double)*3 + 1];
memcpy(&sendBuf, "123456789012345678901234", sendBufLen -1);
_bstr_t bstrt(sendBuf);
```

bstrt has "123456789012378901234"

but when I have weird characters in sendBuf as in for eg. sendBuf[14]   = `"16 'ð' "` which my program needs bstr doesnt get these values from sendBuf

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make this work.  You are copying binary data into a string.  On the .NET side, the char[] gets marshaled to a .NET string, a utf-16 encoded version of the char[] that's converted by applying the system default locale.  Which *changes* the char values.  There's more, the bytes you copy into the char[] may contain a zero, it acts as a string terminator in C strings.

You need to rewrite the C# version to take a byte[] instead.  On the C side, you need to create a SAFEARRAY to match that argument.  Use SafeArrayCreate() to create it.

Comment: I changed the c# code to accept byte[] but I a somewhat lost as what do in cpp to get a byte array from char*

Answer (score 1):

As your edit shows, check out [_bstr_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: @user494461 It's worth noting (and this may or may not be related), that your char buffer is not zero-terminated.  It needs to be `sizeof(double)*3` + 1.  You'd be advised to `memset` that buffer to 0 prior to the `memcpy` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
_bstr_t bstrt(sendBuf);
cpi->Multicast(bstrt);
```